# How to embed a PDF?

Tags: html, pdf

I am trying to embed a PDF in an HTML document, but this seems to work only with Chrome. Other browsers appear to either require plugins or require a user to click a link which is not what I want. Here is what I have tried:

```
<object data="pdfFiles/interfaces.pdf" type="application/pdf">
    <embed src=" pdfFiles/interfaces.pdf" type="application/pdf">&nbsp;</embed>
                    alt :<a href="pdfFiles/interfaces.pdf">
</object>
```

Comment: alt tag is just for texting purpose

Comment: In order to display PDFs in webpages, you need a plug-in.  Chrome just happens to have one built-in.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just add a hyperlink? e.g. `<a href="pdfFiles/interfaces.pdf">Relais D2D</a>`

Comment: @scunliffe I didnt want hyperlink as i just wanted the user to open the pdf file in the browser with pdf embedded inside a different page

Answer (score 61):

Here is the code you can use for every browser:

```
<embed src="pdfFiles/interfaces.pdf" width="600" height="500" alt="pdf" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html">
```

Tested on firefox and chrome

Answer (score 56):

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://example.com/pdf.pdf&embedded=true"
style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Google docs allows you to embed PDFs, Microsoft Office Docs, and other applications by just linking to their services with an iframe. Its user-friendly, versatile, and attractive.

Comment: IMHO this is the best answer. The top-voted one will be browser dependent, and will use the available plugin. By using google viewer , a consistent experienced is guaranteed.

Comment: Note that this probably only works if the file in question isn't behind a password or other kind of wall.

Comment: This is bad if you are on an intranet without internet access.

Comment: I don't understand how a proprietary solution is the best answer. If you have to work on device that doesn't have access to google docs you are just out of luck... Back to IBM times...

Comment: A no go when the pdf needs to remain private ... which probably covers a majority of use cases, if not a significant chunk.

Comment: Google no longer allows you to embed this service in an iframe, due to serving an "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" response header.

Answer (score 33):

This works perfectly and this is official html5.

```
<object data="https://link-to-pdf"></object>
```

Comment: IT works on every browser but It does not work in Google crome while on mobile devices.

Answer (score 16):

do you know about http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/ it is a project by mozila to render pdf inside of your html using canvas. it is super simple to use.

Comment: if you are using reactJS, check this project https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf

Answer (score 6):

I recommend using [PDFObject](http://pdfobject.com/) for PDF plugin detection.

This will only allow you to display alternate content if the user's browser isn't capable of displaying the PDF directly though. For example, the PDF will display fine in Chrome for most users, but they will need a plugin like Adobe Reader installed if they're using Firefox or Internet Explorer.

At least PDFObject will allow you to display a message with a link to download Adobe Reader and/or the PDF file itself if their browser doesn't already have a PDF plugin installed.

Answer (score 0):

[PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) viewer seems like a great solution. Consider using [`pdfjs-viewer-element`](https://github.com/alekswebnet/pdfjs-viewer-element) to simplify PDF.js setup:

```html
<script type="module" src="https://cdn.skypack.dev/pdfjs-viewer-element"></script>
```

Specify the PDF.js release directory with `viewer-path` and path to PDF file with `src` attributes:

```html
<pdfjs-viewer-element
  id="viewer"
  src="/file.pdf"
  viewer-path="/pdfjs-4.0.379-dist"
  style="height: 600px">
</pdfjs-viewer-element>
```

More samples for embedding PDF.js https://github.com/alekswebnet/pdfjs-viewer-element/tree/master/demo

Answer (score -2):

FlexPaper is probably still the best viewer out there to be used for this kind of stuff. It has a traditional viewer and a more turn page / flip book style viewer both in flash and html5

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com

Comment: This is now FlowPlayer, and comes with significant restrictions (e.g. 10 page limit) for their free version: https://flowpaper.com/download/