# Render PDF document inside an object in FireFox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I am using the following code to print a PDF document, in my print button I'm using this code:

```
  Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(" <object id = 'Object1' name='Pdf2' type='application/pdf' width='1' height='1' ><param name='SRC'  value='PrintPDFFile.aspx' /></object> "));
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "MessagePopUp", "<script language=JavaScript>document.Pdf2.printWithDialog();</script>");
```

and in the 'PrintPDFFile.aspx' page , I am creating the PDF

```
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("TEST"));       
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;" + "filename=sample.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
```

This code works fine with IE browser but doesn't work with other browsers such as FF, how it can be modified to work fine with other browsers?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but remove the the line `Response.Write(pdfDoc);` because it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Back to your problem, your iTextSharp code is otherwise correct, your actual problem is with Firefox's rendering of inline PDFs. [See this thread for a discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22534282/231316).

Comment: when I add data tag, it throws an error

Comment: By "throws an error" do you mean that an error is logged to the console? Are you able to provide this error?