# ASP.Net MVC 5 Render PDF in Browser from Byte[] C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I am working with Kendo MVC and I want to render an uploaded PDF into a Tabstrip.

When getting the PDF file to show in the tab, I am calling my controller and subsequent service, getting the file data as a byte array and returning data into its respective div using the following code.

```
public FileStreamResult GetRxPdf(int prescriptionId)
{
    var retVal = _service.GetRxPdf(prescriptionId);
    byte[] byteArray = retVal.FileData;
    MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream();
    pdfStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    pdfStream.Position = 0;
    return new FileStreamResult(pdfStream, retVal.ContentType);
}
```

The rendered output is not the PDF, but is as follows

> %PDF-1.7 %���� 1 0 obj <>/OutputIntents[<>] /Metadata 148 0 R/ViewerPreferences 149 0 R>> endobj 2 0 obj <> endobj 3 0 obj <>/XObject<>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/Annots[ 7 0 R 10 0 R 11 0 R 21 0 R] /MediaBox[ 0 0 595.32 841.92] /Contents 4 0 R/StructParents 0>> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream x��]Ys�F~W��ɔ5�\�I�֒��[9[�yH�@S�̲�����7���=Ip��P�TE��3������1�>[,��&�e��7�ϖ��������������?�N/&���r~w����%~��lr5[|�mq�������$%�W׊e!I8+jAIÊ����ׯ��㣳��ӗ������|w|��eA�H�D����uqy3�����F������G/`�/�G��m�����4r�g����m�**��/s^%�HQ�R�]䛋����]��h1S>�W������R^�0>���՘�Q1(�'l�zL���z>棇��pm0����=�±7�;�� ?��]��ů�>�� ��U�~�O?��a�^���>�A+�xD   %�Ԍ�H�  /�����*��$MD�~�A2V6�Ѣ��Q....more file data here... 
>   0000166807 00000 n trailer <] >> startxref 166853 %%EOF

When the data comes back via an ajax call it this is how it is passed to the div

```
 $("#divRxPdf").html(data);
```

I would be grateful if anyone could help me with this and show the PDF in the Div accordingly.

Comment: Maybe you need to use something like pdf to html.

Comment: whats your column data type to store pdf content data?

Comment: data type in the database is VarBinary(max), content type is stored as a string as 'application/pdf'

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut the PDF is a scanned document, so making this HTML is not an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

PDF needs to be embeded in the HTML with `<embed>`  or `<iframe>` .  You could also use library such as `pdf.js` to render pdf files with some controls.

The pdf.js readme has samples and how to:  https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

---

You can return the pdf as file by passing the binary using `retun File()` method

```
public ActionResult GetRxPdf(int prescriptionId)
 {
    var retVal = _service.GetRxPdf(prescriptionId);
    byte[] byteArray = retVal.FileData;      
   return File(byteArray , "application/pdf" , "Filename.pdf");
}
```

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried and I got the same result, using ActionResult, FileResult, FileContentResult and FileStreamResult

Comment: ideally i dont want to use an iframe, because i want an element of control over the PDF where possible

Comment: Have you tried [pdf.js](http://usefulangle.com/post/20/pdfjs-tutorial-1-preview-pdf-during-upload-wih-next-prev-buttons) ?

Comment: the embed is the way to go in this instance... thanks for your help

Comment: @SimonPrice If your still looking, I was just working on this. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52783009/3590235) is an ASP MVC example I added.

Comment: @user3590235 Thanks brother, ive got a working solution using embed, this was the closest answer to what i needed but ill take a look

Comment: sure, you got it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use object tag to achieve it.

```
$obj = $('<object>'); 
$obj.attr("data","Url to PDF");
$obj.attr("type","application/pdf");

$("#pdfdiv_content").append($obj);
```

For more details refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29941646/what-is-the-best-way-to-display-pdf-in-div-or-panel)

Comment: im not converting html to pdf, the pdf is already uploaded and stored in the database, i have the data, and am passing back its content and its type

Comment: plus, that didnt work, it doesnt show me the file data anymore, just shows me nothing, inepcting the code, the file data is in the div, but nothing rendered