# How to download a pdf file to local disk which opened in html5 pdf viewer

Tags: html, pdf, html5-canvas

The PDF file forced to be opened in html5 which there is no print or download button. How could I save it to my local computer?

The viewer looks similar to this one https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embed Pdf in html5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690000/embed-pdf-in-html5)

Comment: they are different..

Comment: In PDF.js viewer you can execute "javascript:PDFViewerApplication.download()" in the address bar (in very old versions "javascript:PDFView.download()")

Comment: thanks,you mean in explore address bar? seems not working.

Answer (score 2):

[Pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) documents can be downloaded by executing the following javascript from the browser search bar:

```
javascript:PDFViewerApplication.download()
```

Note that in order to execute javascript in the search, this feature must first be enabled:

- In Safari, select "Allow Safari from Smart Search Field" in the Develop menu.
- Chrome and FireFox users can [follow these instructions](https://techdows.com/2014/09/how-to-run-javascript-commands-in-chrome-and-firefox-browsers.html) to enable the feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you see that website or application is using `pdf.js` or id set to `pdfViewer` you can follow following steps. To check inspect the PDF window with the dev tools.

[image: inspect element]

Step: Go to dev tools on your browser and type the following command in the console.

```
PDFViewerApplication.download()
```

This will trigger the download automatically.

#### Screenshot:

[image: console window]