# How to Preview the pdf, Word or Image files from server folder within Laravel application?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.6

I want to preview the image,word or pdf files inside modal popup by Calling a ajax call, on clicking a anchor link and it's also opening the modal popup.

```
 <a href='#' onclick='preview('docId')' title='Preview' data- 
target='#previewModal' data-toggle='modal'> Preview file </a>
```

Ajax code is -

```
function preview(docid)
{
  var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
   $.ajax({
    url : 'docs/viewDoc' ,
    type : 'POST',
    data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, id:docid},
    dataType : 'plain/text  OR  JSON',  ???????
    success : function(d){
        console.log(d.data);
        $('#loader').hide();
       $('#previewModal div.modal-body').html(d.data);
    },
    error : function(d){
        alert('Error - '+ d);
        console.log(d);
    }
 });
}
```

Controller Action Code is -

```
public function viewDoc(Request $request)
{
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $conditions =['docId'=>$id];
  $file_info = Docs::select('path','docType','Title')->where($conditions)- 
   >first();

$file= File::get($file_info->path);
$response = Response::make($file, 200);
$response->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf'); 

return response()->view('admin.docs.test')->with('response',$response);
            OR  ????  how
return response()->view('admin.docs.test',$response,200) ;
            OR   ????? how
 //return response()->json($response,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);   
}
```

PROBLEM is that, how to handle this action response and Set inside the modal popup Body to render the image or file for preview ?

Comment: I think that's not possible for word & pdf docs, but the image you can get the url and set it as src to an image element you create with js

Comment: what should i do? i don't want to view in browser or download the file . @Med.ZAIRI

Comment: for pdf files I think this could help you [http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)

Comment: also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690000/embed-a-pdf-in-html5

Comment: Thanks to @Med.ZAIRI .. I implemented by <embed >. Successfully previewing the files/Images in Modal popup,   but another concern is to prevent the user to print or download the file?