# Pdf Viewer For Spring Web application

Tags: java

I want to display file on jsp page for that I tried Iframe, embed, Object but these are not supporting to large file.

Is there any document viewer which I could use in spring Web application?

Please help me out....

Thanks...

Comment: use <embed> tag. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690000/embed-a-pdf-in-html5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embed a PDF in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690000/embed-a-pdf-in-html5)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GroupDocs.Viewer for Java](https://products.groupdocs.com/viewer/java) API to render the documents as HTML pages or images. Once you have the rendered HTML pages or images, you can embed them into your web application i.e. using an iframe. Alternatively, you can use the Spring-based document viewer application available on [GitHub](https://github.com/groupdocs-viewer/GroupDocs.Viewer-for-Java-Spring).

*Disclosure: I work as a developer evangelist at GroupDocs.*