# File size issue in Chrome for base64-encoded PDF data in OBJECT tag

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, pdf

My problem is related to displaying base64-encoded PDF file data in Chrome browser. The PDF files are not static physical files rather they are streams converted to base64-encoded data. It is a single page application using Node.js backend. The pdf file is displayed in a modal popup box, instead of a new tab or window. The code responsible for displaying the base64-encoded PDF data is given below:

```
var objbuilder = '';
objbuilder += ('<object width="100%" height="100%" data="data:application/pdf;base64,');
objbuilder += (r.response);
objbuilder += ('" type="application/pdf" class="internal">');
objbuilder += ('</object>');
var html = '';
html += '<div class="modal fade in" id="linkedDoc" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">';
html += '<div class="modal-dialog">';
html += '<div class="modal-content" style="height:800px;width:600px;">';
html += '<div class="modal-body" style="height: 100%;" id = "linkedBody">';
html += '<div style="height:25px;clear:both;display:block;">';
html += '<a class="controls previous" href="javascript:void(0);" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</a>';
html += '</div></div></div></div></div>';
$('#linkedDoc').remove();
$('body').append(html);
$('#linkedBody').append(objbuilder);
$('.modal').modal({
    keyboard: false,
    show: true
});
$('.modal-dialog').draggable({
    handle: ".modal-header"
});
$('.modal-content').resizable();
$('#linkedBody').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).find('.modal-body').css({
        'max-height': '100%',
        'max-width': '100%'
    });
});
```

The approach works well for file with almost 1 MB file size but not more than that. Some of the files I want to display are 5 MBs and some are even 10 MBs. How can I fix this issue. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690000/embed-a-pdf-in-html5) SO questions are relevant to the topic but not specific for my situation.

I can't use HTML 'embed' and 'iframe' tags because they need a physical file as their 'src' attribute but I don't have a physical PDF file rather its in-memory data.

Comment: @BusyBee code that do not run should not be wrapped in CodeSnippets.

Comment: So your Server sends the data as a base64 string? Why not as binary directly from an uri?

Comment: @Kaiido _"Why not as binary directly from an uri?"_ What difference it makes?

Comment: well you'd just have to set the data of your object to this uri.

Comment: @Kaiido do you mean that 'data' attribute of 'object' tag can accept binary pdf data instead of base64-encoded data?  if yes, what changes should i do then?

Comment: No i mean it accepts an uri, and if your server provides the binary data when the uri is requested then the object will be able to display the pdf. (Like the most basic scenario)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anyone stumbling upon this question in future, I fixed it using blob:URL technique. [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript) StackOverflow question guided me towards the solution. So instead of opening the PDF file in HTML object element, I opened it in a new window using Blob URL. It could not be achieved using data:URL after Chrome version 60 update in which they blocked data URLs.

Comment: But if I want a page with a pdf inside, then this is not an solution

Answer (score 1):

> First Approach

**Can you try with iframe tag instead of object tag.**

> Second Approach

**can you provide the link for PDF instead of actual data.**

you can create the pdf file and store in some where then after provide the link to object tag.

> Third You can try Embed tag also

May be Solve your issue :)

Comment: third solution: use a blob instead of a base64 string. (javascript solution)

Comment: @GottZ can you post an answer with an example of some reference link, that would be helpful.

Comment: _"Can you try with iframe tag instead of object tag"_ No becasue for iframe we must have a static file physically present somewhere.